# powershell code to find and replace string

Tags: string, powershell, replace, split

I have a string with HTML content.

I want to find few characters and replace with some other string.

For eg:

```
$Content = "This is my string. For more information, goto http://www.example.com/searchpage.htm. You will get the required information here. You can also get information at http://www.example.com/searchpage1.htm. Do not replace sample.htm.  Do not replace sample1.htm."
```

Wherever I find the text `example.com`, I need to replace with `example1.com` and the same URL contains `.htm` which should be made `.html`

If the URL does not contain example.com, I dont want to replace .htm
Below is some part of code, which I could achieve to replace **example.com**
But I am unable to replace .htm part in the same URL.

I dont want to replace .htm all over the main content. 
I just want to replace `.htm` wherever I replace `example.com`

```
$find = "http://www.example.com/"

$newContent = "http://www.example1.com/"

$replacedContent =  $Content -replace $strFind,$strReplace
```

I want to know how to replace a multiple parts of text in a long string.

Please suggest!

Comment: `-replace '\bexample\.com\b','example1.com'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the safest way (in case the URL doesn't contain .htm) but could do it for you:

```
$Content -replace 'http://www\.example\.com(.+?)\.html?', 'http://www.example1.com$1.html'
```

Comment: Thank You, but the URL contains .htm. I need to modify the URL which contains example as well as htm to example1 and .htm

Comment: you mean to .html. my snippet does exactly that - just try it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working for me. I am not sure where I am going wrong. Please guide me

Comment: Suppose the orginal string contains "www.example.com/search-page/searchpage.htm" I need to change it to "www.example1.com/search-content/searchpage.html"